# Mapping SQL-Server Datetime Column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA to map an `Entity` to a table in a SQL Server database for which I've created an `@Embeddable` composite key. There's a column I'd like to use as part of the key and according to SQuirreL its type name is `datetime` and the class name is `java.sql.Timestamp`. The key class looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEntityIdentifier implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "LastUpdateDateTime")
    private Timestamp lastUpdateDateTime;
```

...but the `lastUpdateDateTime` property always resolves to null without error. I've checked and there are no null fields for this column. I've also tried resolving to `java.util.Date` without success. Is there another type I should be using or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you mapping to the table? Could you be using a query or view that isn't including that column?

Comment: With the `@Table` annotation - column is definitely there :/

Comment: the sql server jdbc driver docs say that java.sql.timestamp is the correct type to map to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types

Comment: Yeah, it all looks fine. I'm stumped.

Comment: nailed the little sucker, see answer below in case you ever run into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate will internally convert to a native Java type (i.e. `java.util.Date` as opposed to `java.sql.Timestamp`) by adding the `@Temporal` annotation.

```
@Column(name = "LastUpdateDateTime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date lastUpdateDateTime;
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that this date treatment is not Hibernate-specific, but mandated for any JPA implementation

Comment: Also look into the @DateTimeFormat annotation provided by Spring in case you are using Spring JPA in your project.